# Difference between dot syntax and valueForKey

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, key-value-coding, nstimeinterval

*Please note that update 3 is probably most relevant*

Im setting a `NSTimeInterval` property of a managed object with an nsdate object using `setValue:forKey:`

When i attempt to get the value I get weird stuff, at runtime this

```
NSLog(@"[managedObject valueForKey:@\"startTime\"] : %@, [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[managedObject startTime]]: %@",
[managedObject valueForKey:@"startTime"],[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[managedObject startTime]]);
```

Returns

```
[managedObject valueForKey:@"startTime"] : 2012-07-14 08:13:05 +0000,
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[managedObject startTime]]: 1981-07-14 08:13:05 +0000
```

**Update 1**
The value returned by `[managedObject valueForKey:@"startTime"]` is correct. However I would prefer to use `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[managedObject startTime]]` or something similar so that it is more strongly typed.

I believe `[managedObject startTime]` returns an incorrect value => `363954111.000000` .
However i set it with something like this:

```
managedObject setValue:1342261311 forKey:@"startTime"
```

It is worth noting that I am unsure whether this is incorrect because `[managedObject valueForKey:@"startTime"]` returns a correct NSDate object.

**Update 2**
I've logged the double values returned by KVC and `.` syntax.

```
managedObject.startTime = 363954111.000000
valueForKey timeIntervalSince1970 = 1342261311.000000
```

**Update 3**
Okay, I've set up a test, start time is set like this `entity.startTime = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1342261311] timeIntervalSince1970];` and end time is set like this `[entity setValue:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1342261311] forKey:@"endTime"];`

When i write them to log i get this `start = 1342261311.000000, end = 363954111.000000`

It seems that the NSDate object is being unwrapped incorrectly, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: what type is startTime: NSDate or NSTimeIntervall?

Comment: It is a NSTimeInterval property

Comment: The code you mention in your edit, `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[managedObject startTime]]`, does that not yield the right value? And have you tried to break your code down, i.e., check that `startTime` contains the value you expect before you hand it over to `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:`?

Comment: Then, maybe that is what you should try to chase down - just a suggestion, of course. But I am afraid that I will have to check out of this exchange for now - best of luck with your bug hunting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the difference in epochs. NSDate uses Jan 1 2001 as an epoch. So when I was getting the value I was using the unix epoch (1970). That gave me a difference in values.

When KVC unwraps and wraps NSTimeInterval with a NSDate object it uses the NSDate 2001 epoch.

So instead of using `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970`
I used `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` when getting the value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `valueForKey:` is intended to be used with object values, in fact it returns an `id`.

As a convenience, `valueForKey:` wraps primitive types (such as integers and doubles) in their `NSNumber` counterparts.

The reason you see two different values is that `valueForKey:` returns an `id`, which essentially is a pointer to the position in memory where the `NSNumber` happens to be stored. Your code then just takes this arbitrary memory address and somehow interprets it as a double and then constructs an `NSDate` out of that.

Calling the `startTime` accessor method directly, on the other hand, returns the `double` without any further ado.

If you want to use `valueForKey:`, you can do something like this to get the real value:

```
NSTimeInterval tiv = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"startTime"] doubleValue];
```

and then work from there.

I am actually a bit surprised that the compiler doesn't emit a warning about this. Apple's latest compilers have become quite adept at catching problems like this one.

Comment: Hmm okay, well the valueForKey returns the correct dateTime, I would just prefer to use managedObject.startTime and go from there, so i get compiler warnings if i change the class. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like that is a different question altogether, worthy of some research of its own. A bit more context would also be useful (what code it should be used with, the warnings you get, etc.)

Comment: I attempted to post what i believed was the root of the problem. I understand I didn't explain the problem properly in the question, I have edited it and would prefer to keep it here. I receive no warnings around this, and there isn't much context to provide apart from the action of setting the value. Have you any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimeInterval` is a typdef of a double

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

You can not store scalars directly in core data but you either have to wrap them in a `NSNumber`  or in your case it may be easier to use a `NSDate`.

Comment: I selected use scalar properties when generating the managed objects. The question isn't, can I use it. It is why I am getting weird results without using key value coding

Answer (score 0):

If startTime is a NSTimeInterval (and not an NSDate), you are comparing two different things there, a double and an NSDAte object.

`[managedObject valueForKey:@"startTime"]` will return you an NSTimeInterval, a primitive (which you should print with %f by the way).

`[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[managedObject startTime]]` will return you a NSDate.

If you really want to comare the two, you should use `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[managedObject valueForKey:@"startTime"]]` to properly compare two NSDate objects.

Comment: startTime is an NSTimeInterval, however using valueForKey returns an instance of NSDate. Where as managedObject.startDate returns a NSTimeInterval value, thats why i use dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 on the latter. Furthermore i get a badAccess error when i use %f, enforcing the fact that valueForKey returns a date object.